# Asp.net Web API OData model configuration globally

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a class called `Application`

```
public class Application
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; internal set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; internal set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; internal set; }
}
```

I map the `Code First` model configuration using `Fluent API`

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ApplicationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Code).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.DateCreated).HasColumnType("date");
    }
}

public class ApplicationsUnitOfWork : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }  

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ModelsConfiguration.ApplicationConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Now, i need to implement `OData` for the `Application` entities.

Here is the configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var applicationConfig = builder.EntitySet<Application>("Applications");
        applicationConfig.EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        applicationConfig.EntityType.Property(p => p.Id).Name = "id";
        applicationConfig.EntityType.Property(p => p.Name).Name = "name";
        applicationConfig.EntityType.Ignore(p => p.DateCreated);

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, the specified `OData` configuration works only under "odata" route. Ex: `localhost:port\odata\Applications`.

Is there a way to apply the `OData` configuration globally?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the OData configuration globally"? Can you explain with a sample which is exactly what you want to achieve? Is not clear at all!!

Comment: Yes. You mentioned "the specified OData configuration", what's it?